# How do I include javascript+css from node_modules in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

I need to include fullcalendar and chart.js within my ionic 2 app.  (ionic 2 RC.3)
I have used npm to install the relevant modules, and the scripts are within my node_modules folder.
How do I properly include the scripts/css from the node_modules folder into my app?

Things I've tried:

- Manually copy the relevant js/css files into the www folder, and
  references them with normal `<script>` and `<link>` elements in the index.html.
  (I mostly got this to work, but it seems terribly clunky)
- import them in my app.module.ts and/or my custom component.ts files, such as 
  `import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js';`
  (this sort of works, but I get errors that the underlying scripts can't find jQuery, so I still have to include jQuery in the index.html manually as above)

Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 15):

I believe this is the cleanest way I've seen it done.

We're essentially going to override the copy portion of the ionic build script.  They've created the build script to encourage this and make it simple.

Assuming you've already used npm to install whatever library you need:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

(which installs the chart.js library into the node_packages folder in the root of the project)

Look at **/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/copy.config.js**.  This is what we are overriding, so copy it's contents to a file at **/config/copy.config.js** (You'll need to create the /config folder).

```
module.exports = {
  include: [
    {
      src: '{{SRC}}/assets/',
      dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/'
    },
    {
      src: '{{SRC}}/index.html',
      dest: '{{WWW}}/index.html'
    },
    {
      src: '{{SRC}}/manifest.json',
      dest: '{{WWW}}/manifest.json'
    },
    {
      src: '{{SRC}}/service-worker.js',
      dest: '{{WWW}}/service-worker.js'
    },
    {
      src: 'node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js',
      dest: '{{BUILD}}/polyfills.js'
    },
    {
      src: 'node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/',
      dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts/'
    },
    {
      src: './node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js',
      dest: '{{BUILD}}/Chart.bundle.min.js'
    },
  ]
};
```

The last section was the one we added on, to copy the chart.js file to somewhere that will actually get pulled into the build.

To get our script be used, package.json needs to be told about it, so add this "config" section to your /package.json file:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
},
```

Now when you build, the file will be copied, and it's obviously easier after the first one is done, to add more.  There are other portions of the ionic build process you can override as well, it's worth looking in to.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/

Now you can call it in easily, one option is inside of index.html:

```
<script src="build/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The benefits are, if you install a module update, changed files will get updated in your build, and also, everything works out easily with vcs and setting up new environments, as the dependencies are handled by npm, and our script extension takes care of everything else.  :-)

Hope that helps!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked, sort of. However, since I added "ionic_copy" to package.json, live reload feature of my Ionic 2 project stopped working. Let's say I modified a .ts file on my project directory, and saved it, live reload should refresh working project automatically but now it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for that solution, that helped a lot.

Comment: This suggestion works great! However, if you don't want to add tags to your index file, use import statements in your ts files and @import statements in your sass files instead. Overriding copy.config.js requires that you also override the watch.config.js file so that your live reload works. Just copy the original config in @ionic/app-scripts/config and point the require() commands to the relative node_modules location. Cheers