# How to install external JS for ionic 3 (leaflet locatecontrol)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet

How to install this plugin for ionic ? there is one javascript file and one scss file.

https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol

i followed instructions i used npm install then tried to include but couldnt make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include javascript+css from node\_modules in ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943914/how-do-i-include-javascriptcss-from-node-modules-in-ionic-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install a js library and import it in Typescript file, you need to have a type declaration file.
For [leaflet-locatecontrol](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol), it is present in [DefinitelyTyped library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/leaflet.locatecontrol) and can be saved from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet.locatecontrol)

```
npm i @types/leaflet.locatecontrol --save-dev
```

In order to use in a typescript file do:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.locatecontrol';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.What about this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.smooth_marker_bouncing I couldnt see it in typed library

Comment: if it is not there then you will have to probably write one or raise an issue in github